# JWT token request results in invalid_grant & unsupported_grant_type

Tags: jwt, docusignapi

I created a JWT Token following the steps described on [DocuSign website](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken).

When the API Management layer sends the JWT Token to `https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token`

```
curl -X POST -d 'grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=***JWTTOKEN***' 'https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token'
```

(`***JWTTOKEN***` being a placeholder for the actual token)

to it results in:

```
{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "unsupported_grant_type"
}
```

Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

used apigees GenerateJWT to create token.

used [.net SDK](https://github.com/docusign/docusign-csharp-client/blob/master/sdk/src/DocuSign.eSign/Client/ApiClient.cs) for inspiration.